# curl to httr for Rosette API invalid method

Tags: r, curl, httr

So I finally get my ping command working using httr as script below

```
library(httr)
curl_com  = GET("https://api.rosette.com/rest/v1/ping", add_headers(`X-RosetteAPI-Key` = "my api"))
```

Great stuff but now cos Im stucked at the next bit.

Now I want to call another api to do sentiment analysis

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-RosetteAPI-Key: your_api_key" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
-d '{"content": "Original Ghostbuster Dan Aykroyd, who also co-wrote the 1984 Ghostbusters film, couldn’t be more pleased with the new all-female Ghostbusters cast, telling The Hollywood Reporter, “The Aykroyd family is delighted by this inheritance of the Ghostbusters torch by these most magnificent women in comedy.”" }' \
"https://api.rosette.com/rest/v1/sentiment"
```

I got error 405 - Method Not Allowed – You tried to access the Rosette API with an invalid method. I dont know how to translate the above curl command using httr can someone please talk me thru step by step?

Hope someone can help please
Peddie

Comment: You are aware Rosette has an [R package](https://github.com/rosette-api/R-Binding) for their API, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while my comment that they have R code to use was correct, it's horribad R code.

You can now just use the `rosette` R package to access the full API. Just make sure to put your Rosette API key into `ROSETTE_API_KEY` (easiest to just edit `~/.Renviron`).

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/rosette")

ros_sentiment("Original Ghostbuster Dan Aykroyd, who also co-wrote the 1984 Ghostbusters film, couldn’t be more pleased with the new all-female Ghostbusters cast, telling The Hollywood Reporter, 'The Aykroyd family is delighted by this inheritance of the Ghostbusters torch by these most magnificent women in comedy.'")
## $document
## $document$label
## [1] "pos"
## 
## $document$confidence
## [1] 0.7962072
## 
## 
## $entities
##           type            mention         normalized count entityId sentiment.label sentiment.confidence
## 1       PERSON        Dan Aykroyd        Dan Aykroyd     2  Q105221             pos            0.6385089
## 2 ORGANIZATION Hollywood Reporter Hollywood Reporter     1   Q61503             pos            0.5338094
```

The rest of the API is also there:

- `rosette_api_key`:    Get or set ROSETTE_API_KEY value
- `ros_categories`: Rosette API categorizatioin service
- `ros_embedding`:  Rosette API text embedding service
- `ros_entities`:   Rosette API entity extraction service
- `ros_info`:   Rosette API version info
- `ros_language`:   Rosette API language identification service
- `ros_make_name`:  Make a Name object
- `ros_morph`:  Rosette API morphological analysis service
- `ros_name_similarity`:    Rosette API version info
- `ros_name_translation`:   Rosette API name translation service
- `ros_ping Rosette`: API availability
- `ros_relationships`:  Rosette API relationship extraction service
- `ros_sentences`:  Rosette API sentence determination service
- `ros_sentiment`:  Rosette API sentiment analysis service
- `ros_tokens`: Rosette API tokenizatioin service

It will be on CRAN a bit later in the month (when I have time to polish it a bit).

Comment: Im not familiar with devtools::instal_github("hrbrmstr/rosette") part of the script so do I just copy and paste that in R console?

Comment: aye. (I also fixed the typo). I'm working with the Rosette folks to get it on CRAN soon

Answer (score 2):

The simple conversion from the `curl` command to `httr` has the end result that looks like this:

```
response = POST("https://api.rosette.com/rest/v1/sentiment",
                add_headers(
                  `X-RosetteAPI-Key` = "",
                  `Content-Type` = "application/json",
                  Accept = "application/json",
                  `Cache-Control` = "no-cache"
                ),
                content = list(content = "Original Ghostbuster Dan Aykroyd, who also co-wrote the 1984 Ghostbusters film, couldn’t be more pleased with the new all-female Ghostbusters cast, telling The Hollywood Reporter, 'The Aykroyd family is delighted by this inheritance of the Ghostbusters torch by these most magnificent women in comedy.'"))
```

Let's walk through.

1. In your original `curl` command, there are four lines that begin with `-H`. Those are *header* statements, and so become part of the `add_headers` command in `httr::GET`.
2. In `curl`, the `-d` command refers to *data*, and the [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) suggests that it sends a `POST` request with that data as the content. Given that, we use `httr::POST` with the `content` argument.

You can replace this line:

```
`X-RosetteAPI-Key` = "",
```

... with your appropriate key. Since I don't have a key, when I look at the response I get unauthorized:

```
content(response)

#> $code
#> [1] "unauthorized"
#> 
#> $message
#> [1] "authentication required to access this resource"
```

Comment: This is really useful step by step thank you. When I put my API in I got a message Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't connect to server ....?